# React - reuse state of parent component in component imported as children prop

Tags: reactjs, state

I want to pass event prop from Child to Parent, so when we click the button in Child component, state from Parent should be triggered.

Let's assume that we have two components, `Parent` and `Child`, but `Child` will not be imported directly in `Parent`, like this

```
export default function Parent() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = num => {
    setCount(current => current + num);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Child handleClick={handleClick} />

      <h2>Count: {count}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and it's very straitforward to pass prop in this case, but how to do when we have situation when Parent does not know which component will be passed as `{children}` prop, like this:

```
export default function Parent({children}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = num => {
    setCount(current => current + num);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and later we import some child component

```
<Parent>
   <Child />
</Parent>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) along with [`React.Children.map`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap). `cloneElement` clones and returns a new React element using a given element as the starting point. You can add props, ref and keys on top.
`React.Children.map` will invoke a function on every immediate child.

```
//function body
....

let newChildren =  React.Children.map(children, (child) => React.cloneElement(child, { handleClick })
);

 return (
    <div>
      {newChildren}
    </div>
  );
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-lumiere-xfgpb3?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but where to import newChildren in this case , then we should call `newChildren` instead of `children` between div tags ?

Comment: You just define it in the function body and call it in your return. I missed something, and have updated it.

Comment: I think this will work but actually I don't need .map, because it will be just one component , how to do that or it's necessary to have .map?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Actually, `React.children.map` would be the right and recommended way to do this and you do not have to care about anything. Link https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-lumiere-xfgpb3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I am using TypeScript and getting with warning message for child element.
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactPortal | null | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'.

Answer (score 0):

This would couple parent to a child. `children` property is specifically to make sure parent does not care what the child is.

Push the state & callback up the component hierarchy, to the component that knows specific types of both parent and child components.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

return (<Parent count={count}>
    <Child onClick={num => setCount(count => count + num} />
</Parent>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, You can achieve this via `cloneElement` like this.

```
export const Parent = ({children}) => {

const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('okk')
}

return (
    <div>
        { React.cloneElement(children, { handleClick} )}
    </div>
)}
```

and now you are able to trigger `handleClick` function from the child component.